# Postman Monitor fails a Request that passes all tests locally

Tags: postman

I wrote a simple Postman Collection containing some Requests against an API I use for calculating gaming based stuff.

Locally, the Requests work as intended. On a Monitor, they seem to not be sending any body.

I do have COntent-Type set to application/json manually in the header. My request has a JSON Body.

You can test request the API at https://ffxiv-dps.herokuapp.com/dps
with the following body:

```
{
    "job": "PLD",
    "stats": {
        "WD": 109,
        "Strength": 2735,
        "DirectHit": 785,
        "CriticalHit": 2625,
        "Determination": 1075,
        "SkillSpeed": 1133,
        "Vitality": 3754,
        "Tenacity": 852,
        "Defense": 5737
    }
}
```

My tests look like this:

```js
pm.test("Response is ok", function() {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

pm.test("Response Body has JSON with data", function() {
    pm.response.to.have.jsonBody("StatisticIntervals");
    pm.response.to.have.jsonBody("DamagePerSecond");
});

pm.test("Response Body has valid JSON Data", function() {
    var responseJSON = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(responseJSON.StatisticIntervals.CriticalHit).to.be.ok;
        console.log("Critical Hit is OK");
    pm.expect(responseJSON.StatisticIntervals.DirectHit).to.be.ok;
        console.log("Direct Hit is OK");
    pm.expect(responseJSON.StatisticIntervals.Determination).to.be.ok;
        console.log("Determination is OK");
    pm.expect(responseJSON.StatisticIntervals.SkillSpeed).to.be.ok;
        console.log("Skill Speed is OK"); 
    pm.expect(responseJSON.StatisticIntervals.Tenacity).to.be.ok;
        console.log("Tenacity is OK");
    pm.expect(responseJSON.StatisticIntervals.Defense).to.be.ok;
        console.log("Defense is OK");
    pm.expect(responseJSON.DamagePerSecond).to.be.ok;
        console.log("DPS is OK");
})
```

Note that this web server is running on a Heroku dyno so it might take a bit getting out of idle state.

With that you should be able to reproduce the problem - it will work locally but won't work using a Monitor (My API will response with 400: Bad Request - which is fine but not what this request should produce).

Answer (score 0):

Running the following request:

```
curl --location --request GET "https://ffxiv-dps.herokuapp.com/dps" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data "{
    \"job\": \"PLD\",
    \"stats\": {
        \"WD\": 109,
        \"Strength\": 2735,
        \"DirectHit\": 785,
        \"CriticalHit\": 2625,
        \"Determination\": 1075,
        \"SkillSpeed\": 1133,
        \"Vitality\": 3754,
        \"Tenacity\": 852,
        \"Defense\": 5737
    }
}"
```

locally as well as on a monitor produces the same results, which is that all the tests pass.

[image]

Comment: Appears to have been an issue with Monitors at that time, it's resolved for me now as well.